# post request is not working in vue js.Console says POST http://localhost/3000/cars net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: vue.js

If I use post request in a vue project, it is not working and the console says:

> POST http://localhost/3000/cars net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your url `http://localhost/3000/cars`, i bet that `3000` is the port based on your error,ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (which means the destination cannot be reached).

You have a forward slash `/` instead of `:`.

The correct URL should be:

**http://localhost:3000/cars**

Comment: http://localhost:3000/cars i write at this.get request is working , but post is not working.

Comment: You need to enable post to catch parameters, put this above all routes `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` , also, share your code if you have any problems. I can't help you only by guessing your problems.

Comment: I checked all the solutions, but couldn't make it work,  what could be the possible reasone?